# Django DetailView show last if no pk in url

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

With a class based DetailView is there a way to say "if no pk is specified" when the url is called, just use `MyModel.object.last()` as object reference?

```
url(r'^(?:(?P<pk>\d+)/)?detail/$', views.MyDetailView.as_view()),

class MyDetailView(DetailView):
    model = MyModel
    if self.kwargs['pk'] == False:
       self.object = MyModel.object.last()
```

I'm running Django 1.11

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can override the `get_object` method. Note you should be checking whether `pk` is set in `self.kwargs`, not whether it is equal to `False`.

```
def get_object(self):
    if 'pk' not in self.kwargs:
        return MyModel.objects.last()
    return super(MyDetailView, self).get_object()
```